# Using C++ code with OpenGL in a Cocoa application

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, opengl

I have created a Rubick's Cube model in OpenGL on C++ and now need to make it into an app for OS X.

I have found a tutorial(https://riptutorial.com/opengl/example/13875/creating-opengl-4-1-with-cplusplus-and-cocoa) on that matter, however, I can't follow it completely as I need the main menu(on the top bar) to still be usable and catch events in order to manipulate the cube.

I have the necessary methods to manipulate the cube, the main problem is to call them from Obj-C code which is responsible for the Cocoa app itself. Is there a way to link what view controller displays with the C++ code responsible for drawing and how do I catch and process events if I need to summon C++ code for that?

I do understand that I basically need a wrapper for the C++ code, however, I struggled to find any up to date info(guides, similar topics on StackOverflow, etc.) on the matter.

Comment: You can mix Objective-C code with C++ code in the same file by giving it the `.mm` extension (when compiling in Xcode).  Does that help?

Comment: @PaulSanders the code on C++ works fine with Objective-C if you create a shared pointer and use the application that way for one purpose(basically if the goal is to draw the same image over and over again), however, what I need is to call different methods from different parts of the Objective-C code handling the app, to be able to manipulate the cube. The question is more about Cocoa than using C++ code with Obj-C in general

Comment: @PaulSanders, unfortunately, I can't simply merge my C++ and Objective-C code due to the task at the uni being to write in C++

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  It's straightforward to call C++ code from Objective-C, if that's the issue you are struggling with.

Comment: I guess I should add that you have to build the UI (e.g. menu and button handlers) in Objective-C, whatever your uni might say.